# How to style the RSS wordpress?

Tags: plugins, widgets, css, rss

I am using the default rss feed widget but want to style it. My question is -where to add my piece of code to style the default wordpress rss widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add XSLT sheet to the RSS declaration. It will automatically beautify the RSS XML.

You have a tutorial [here](http://kirstiebirr.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/how-to-integrate-wordpress-rss-feed-into-your-website-using-xslt/)

Otherwise, just use "Advanced RSS" plugin, that allows you to configure the graphics with it ( via XSLT ). Plugin page [here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-rss/)